# Codeigniter query empty response on Godaddy but works in localhost fine

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Codeigniter connect with database but no query response from database table. My database is already converted from Postgresql to Mysql,our table type is InnoDB,but I create a sample table in Godaddy server that's table type is MyISAM.I don't know what's the problem i facing

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

login_view.php

```
var name = {
ajax: 1,
name: $('#login-username').val()
}
$.ajax({
 url:  base_url+"login/username_validation",
type: 'POST',
data: name,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data)
{      
$.each(data.response.userid, function (a, b) 
{
if((b.count) == 1)
{
$("#login").removeAttr("style");
$(".alertbox").css("display", "none");       
$("#login-password") .focus();
}
});
```

login.php

```
public function username_validation()
{
    if ($this->input->post('ajax'))
    {   
        $username = $this->input->post('name');
        $result['userid'] = $this->common_model->chk_username($username);
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array('response'=>$result)));
    }
}
```

common_model.php

```
public function chk_username($username)
 {
    $this->db->select('count(*) as count');
    $this->db->from('mas_user');
    $this->db->where('login_id',$username);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
 }
```

mysql table

```
user_creation_id    login_id   password
    1                 admin     admin123
```

post

```
ajax : 1
name :admin
```

response

```
{"response":{"userid":[]}}
status 200 ok
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is on your login.php you are asking if ajax is equals to true, when ajax is actually equal to 1.

Try using one of the following two options

In your login.php

```
if ($this->input->post('ajax') == 1)
```

or in your login_view.php

```
var name = {
ajax: true,
name: $('#login-username').val()
}
```